# Prevent File Manager from accessing system folders

Tags: java, android

I'm working on making a secure android 6.0 ROM, and amongst other things users won't have root access.

At the moment I'm stucked with the File Manager.

I use as a base Amaze File Manager because it's good looking and has many options, but the problem is that it can navigate back from the sdcard and reach the root/system folders which is what I want to prevent users from doing.

It uses

`Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory().getAbsolutePath() + "/";`

and I guess that's where the problem comes from.

I have tried to change it to

`Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory().getPath();`

or to

`Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory() + "/sdcard";`

or to

`Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory().getRelativePath() + "/sdcard";`

without any success, I think that the fact that it imports Environment makes it capable of browsing the whole storage.

So, how could I modify the code to prevent that File manager from accessing the root/system folders?

As a side note, the path to the sdcard is /sdcard, and the path to the external sd is /storage/sdcard1.

Any suggestion will be much appreciated, thanks in advance.

Comment: Nonsense. Every app can browse the whole system starting with absolute path "/". What does that possibility have to do with a micro SD card or anything else?

Comment: Nonsense yourself, if you had read a bit more carefully you d have understood that the question was how to prevent an app that has absolute path and "/" to read the system folders. Who you think you are?